# how to get a fresh copy of a project from cvs?

Tags: eclipse, cvs, restore

I"m running eclipse and cvs. I want to get a fresh copy from cvs as right clicking and using the team replace/synchronize etc. does not work. how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the way to do it is use "Import" and then select "from CVS". This will get you a clean copy of the project, regardless of the state of your system.

Using "Replace With" did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have checked out from CVS, right click on the project and use *Replace With>Latest from HEAD*. That will remove all changes and set the project to be HEAD.  Don't use options that are under *Team*.